# Reapeater Control button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I click on the vote button the detail will insert but all the the page detail insert I want only perticular button click data should insert.

[image]

Code:

```
Protected Sub vote(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) {
//( lblName,lbl_id ,lbl_name,Label1 this is all reapeater field id )

    Dim lblName As Label
    Dim lbl_id As Label
    Dim lbl_name As Label
    Dim Label1 As Label

    For Each item As RepeaterItem In rpt_path.Items
        lblName = CType(item.FindControl("lblName"), Label)
        lbl_id = CType(item.FindControl("lbl_id"), Label)
        lbl_name = CType(item.FindControl("lbl_name"), Label)
        Label1 = CType(item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)

        con=("Connection String")
        con.Open()

        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("insert into CFC(C_E_No,Name,Class_id,Party_id)values(@C_E_No,@Name,@Class_id,@Party_id)", con)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@C_E_No", CType(item.FindControl("lblName"), Label).Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CType(item.FindControl("lbl_id"), Label).Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class_id", CType(item.FindControl("lbl_name"), Label).Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Party_id", CType(item.FindControl("Label1"), Label).Text)

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want to do a for each to repeat over all the RepeaterItems. Hard to say though without that code.

Comment: Can we see the source code for the repeater markup?

Comment: Are you inserting all the data? I need some more clarity in order to answer this. If you only want to insert specific data, then you only need to pass that specific data to the query or procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Design
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_iid" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_iname" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_icid" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ipid" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
Coding on Vote Button Click
Protected Sub vote(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim str As String = CType(sender, Button).CommandArgument
        Session("vid") = str
        MsgBox(Session("vid"))

       Connection String
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from candi where C_E_No='" & str.ToString() & "' ")
        ds = New DataSet
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
        da.Fill(ds, "candi")
        lbl_iid.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0)
        lbl_iname.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString()
        lbl_icid.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()
        lbl_ipid.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4).ToString()

        con.Close()
     Connection String 
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into CFC(Stu_E_No,C_E_No,Name,Class_id,Party_id)values('" & Session("stdid") & "','" & lbl_iid.Text & "','" & lbl_iname.Text & "','" & lbl_icid.Text & "','" & lbl_ipid.Text & "')  ")
        MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Succes")
```